# I am just having a lesson at school

Tags: present-continuous

I know that there exists some cases when "have" can be used in the progressive form. But not sure if this usage is permissible in this context: I am at school in the class. My phone rings and I answer:

*Do not bother me I am just having a lesson at school.*

Comment: Footnote: Perhaps the best way to say this is: _Don't bother me; class just started_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb is OK, but simply "in a lesson" might be better. "having a lesson" makes it sound like you have a private tutor.

[just](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/just) is appropriate when you are talking about something that happened a very short while ago.

> The class has **just** started. - it start a couple of minutes ago.

If you use **just** in your sentence, it is not appropriate for the "a very short while ago" meaning, so I would take it as the "only" meaning, which suggests that the lesson is not very important.

> Do not bother me, I am just/only having a lesson at school.

If you want to talk about something that is happening at the moment, and is likely to continue, you can say **just now**

> Do not bother me, I am having a lesson at school **just now**.